# Check which option is selected and control the list items to be displayed with respect to the selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm fairly new to jquery/js. 
I'm trying to control which list items to show with respect to the selected option. 
The first condition in the script works as I like but the second condition doesn't.
I'm not sure why the :nth-of-type(2):selected doesn't work when the :nth-of-type(1):selected works?

Also, I don't really know jquery by the book so I'm not really sure if this is the right approach to this.

Any answer or suggestion would greatly be appreciated!

Thanks.

```js
var $monthlyOption = '#monthly option';
var $list = '.top-list ul li';

$(document).ready(function() {

  if ($($monthlyOption).is(':nth-of-type(1):selected')) {

    $($list).slice(0, 5).removeClass('hide-me')

  } else if ($($monthlyOption).is(':nth-of-type(2):selected')) {

    $($list).slice(5, 10).removeClass('hide-me')

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <select id="monthly">
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="top-list">
  <ul>
    <li class="hide-me">list item</li>
    <li class="hide-me">list item</li>
    <li class="hide-me">list item</li>
    <li class="hide-me">list item</li>
    <li class="hide-me">list item</li>
    <li class="hide-me">list item</li>
    <li class="hide-me">list item</li>
    <li class="hide-me">list item</li>
    <li class="hide-me">list item</li>
    <li class="hide-me">list item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
var $monthlyOption = '#monthly option';
var $list = '.top-list ul li';

$(document).ready(function() {

  if ($($monthlyOption).is(':nth-of-type(1):selected')) {

    $($list).slice(0, 5).removeClass('hide-me')

  } else if ($($monthlyOption).is(':nth-of-type(2):selected')) {

    $($list).slice(5, 10).removeClass('hide-me')

  }
  $('#monthly').on('change', function() {
    if ($($monthlyOption).is(':nth-of-type(1):selected')) {

      $($list).slice(0, 5).removeClass('hide-me')

    } else if ($($monthlyOption).is(':nth-of-type(2):selected')) {

      $($list).slice(5, 10).removeClass('hide-me')

    }
  });
});
```

```css
.hide-me {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <select id="monthly">
      <option>Option 1</option>
      <option>Option 2</option>
      <option>Option 3</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="top-list">
  <ul>
    <li class="hide-me">list item1</li>
    <li class="hide-me">list item2</li>
    <li class="hide-me">list item3</li>
    <li class="hide-me">list item4</li>
    <li class="hide-me">list item5</li>
    <li class="hide-me">list item6</li>
    <li class="hide-me">list item7</li>
    <li class="hide-me">list item8</li>
    <li class="hide-me">list item9</li>
    <li class="hide-me">list item10</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The reason its not working its because you don't have a `change` event. Add a change event to `#monthly` and just add your condition in there and it will work.

Comment: I see that was it! 
Thank you so much!

Comment: @Dixiekun I'm glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.......

```js
var monthlyOption = '#monthly option';
var list = '.top-list ul li';

$(document).ready(function() {

if($("select[name='monthly']")[0].selectedIndex == 0)
    {
    $(list).slice(0, 5).removeClass('hide-me');
    $(list).slice(5, 10).addClass('hide-me');
    }

 if($("select[name='monthly']")[0].selectedIndex == 1)
    {

    $(list).slice(5, 10).removeClass('hide-me');
     $(list).slice(0, 5).addClass('hide-me');

  }
  if($("select[name='monthly']")[0].selectedIndex == 2)
    {

    $(list).slice(5, 10).addClass('hide-me');
     $(list).slice(0, 5).addClass('hide-me');

  }
  $('#monthly').on('change', function() 
  {
    if($("select[name='monthly']")[0].selectedIndex == 0)
    {
    $(list).slice(0, 5).removeClass('hide-me');
     $(list).slice(5, 10).addClass('hide-me');
    }

 if($("select[name='monthly']")[0].selectedIndex == 1)
    {

    $(list).slice(5, 10).removeClass('hide-me');
     $(list).slice(0, 5).addClass('hide-me');

  }
  
   if($("select[name='monthly']")[0].selectedIndex == 2)
    {

    $(list).slice(5, 10).addClass('hide-me');
     $(list).slice(0, 5).addClass('hide-me');

  }
  
  });

});
```

```css
.hide-me
{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <select id="monthly" name="monthly">
  <option selected>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="top-list">
  <ul>
    <li class="hide-me">list item1</li>
    <li class="hide-me">list item2</li>
    <li class="hide-me">list item3</li>
    <li class="hide-me">list item4</li>
    <li class="hide-me">list item5</li>
    <li class="hide-me">list item6</li>
    <li class="hide-me">list item7</li>
    <li class="hide-me">list item8</li>
    <li class="hide-me">list item9</li>
    <li class="hide-me">list item10</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Added a change event to select box ( #monthly). Instead of getting :nth-of-type(2):selected changed as "select[name='monthly']")[0].selectedIndex". It is another way of checking the selected position.

Comment: In your answer please instead of comments.